# Error when configuring Kafka Avro serializer and deserializer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In the Spring Boot application, using Kafka Spring, and trying to configure the Avro serializers and desrializers in the application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: >
        org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          deserializer:
            key:
              delegate:
                class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value:
              delegate:
                class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
```

And when loading up the app via a docker image to run the integration tests against it, it returns:

```
Caused by:
13:15:47                                      org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer' to java.lang.Class<?>

Caused by:
13:15:47                                              org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class'; Could not find class [io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer]
13:15:47                                                  at app//org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:79)
13:15:47                                                  at app//org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:45)
13:15:47                                                  at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$TypeConverterConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:221)
13:15:47                                                  at app//org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
13:15:47                                                  ... 220 more
13:15:47  
13:15:47                                                  Caused by:
13:15:47                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer]
13:15:47                                                      at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:333)
13:15:47                                                      at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:65)
13:15:47                                                      at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:425)
13:15:47                                                      at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:398)
13:15:47                                                      at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
13:15:47                                                      at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
13:15:47                                                      ... 223 more
```

Any help to provide valid configurations would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the avro serializer/deserializer jar is not on the class path.

Comment: Hi Gary, would providing the "io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer" dependency solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please point me to what are the valid dependencies for this, please?

Comment: Don't use manual jar files. Use Maven/Gradle instead to manage dependencies... The Confluent documentation tells what maven repo you need to add. Their jars are not in maven central

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer, I'm using Gradle and struggling to find the exact dependencies for that. Have found only the serializer one so far (and not sure if it's a valid source though): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer?repo=confluent-packages

Comment: Yes, that is the correct one. See https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/java/#prerequisites